# Unexpected "End-of-Transmission character" (\x04 or ^D) in binary

Tags: apache-beam

```
msg:b'\x04{"origin": "fluentd", "timestamp": "2021-12-18T01:21:17.683Z", "collected_at": "2021-12-18T01:21:17.683Z"}'
```

This happens with apache_beam.io.kafka (Apache Beam 2.30). Python API.

What could be the cause?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps the `b'\x04` notation is not recognized for some reason?

Comment: Looks like you are serializing twice.